# Workflow 2010 is not sending emails insdie sharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, smtp

I have created a workflow 2010 using SharePoint designer 2013, as follow:-

[image]

and i assign the workflow to a tracking list. and inside my CA 2013, under system setting --> Configure outgoing e-mail settings i added the smtp server name as `outlook.ad-domainA.intra` and the from field as `info@ouremail.com`. but if users create or edit an item inside the tracking list no emails is being sent to the AssignedTo users list.
can anyone advice ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tested to see if SharePoint can send emails through other avenues, like alerts?  Simplest way woul dbe to sign up for an elert on a doc library.

Comment: no i tried to define an alert, but it mentioned that this web application can not send emails..

Comment: Sounds like your SP environment hasn't been configured completely to end emails.  See these articles
[TechNet Configure SP Outbound Email](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462.aspx) -- 

[Good Blog about configuring Exchange](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-outgoing-email-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: The problem is that i need to define the  SMTP port number and username and password to be able to connect to the SMTP server. while inside SharePoint CA outgoing email configuration i can only define the server name, send from , reply-to all. but i can not find a way to define the SMTP port number and the username and password . can you advice please? thanks

Comment: You'll either have to configure your Exchange server to allow your SP server to send email or configure SMTP on your SP server and realy it to your Exchange server.  The latter will let you authenticate.